# Remove character if NOT between two letters

Tags: regex

Suppose that I have a text like below

```
Lorem Ipsum-is simply dummy- text of the printing and -typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum - has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
a-z
```

I want to remove `-` character if it is NOT between two characters ([a-zA-Z]). So, the desired output is:

```
Lorem Ipsum-is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum  has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
a-z
```

How can I write a regex to match this case?

Comment: just for your information.. that's called negative lookbehind and negative lookahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove what is preceded by something that is not `[a-zA-Z]` AND everything that is not followed by `[a-zA-Z]`:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])-|-(?![a-zA-Z])
```

Comment: I think the correct expression to catch the dash having that condition is just `(?<![a-zA-Z])-(?![a-zA-Z])` .. followed by a replacement empty string. I didn't get why did you use `-|-` instead

Comment: @DiegoD that fails to catch `... and -types...`. Which should be removed as well.